# How can I compose resources in Scala while still closing them correctly with scala-arm?

Tags: scala, resource-management, autocloseable, scala-arm

I have a class that takes a local file, transforms it, and stores it in GCS:

```
import java.nio.channels.Channels
import java.nio.file.{ Files, Path }
import java.util.zip.{ GZIPOutputStream, ZipInputStream }

import com.google.cloud.storage.{ BlobInfo, Storage }
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import resource._


class GcsService(gcsStorage: Storage) {

  def storeFileInGcs(localPath: Path, destination: FileDestination): Unit = {
    val blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(destination.bucket, destination.path).build

    if (destination.unzipGzip) {
      for (input ← managed(new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(localPath)));
           output ← managed(new GZIPOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(gcsStorage.writer(blobInfo))))) {
        ByteStreams.copy(input, output)
      }
    } else if (destination.decompressBzip2) {
      for (input <- managed(new BZip2CompressorInputStream(Files.newInputStream(localPath)));
           output <- managed(Channels.newOutputStream(gcsStorage.writer(blobInfo)))) {
        ByteStreams.copy(input, output)
      }
    } else {
      for (input <- managed(Files.newInputStream(localPath));
           output <- managed(Channels.newOutputStream(gcsStorage.writer(blobInfo)))) {
        IOUtils.copy(input, output)
      }
    }
  }

}

case class FileDestination(unzipGzip: Boolean, decompressBzip2: Boolean, bucket: String, path: String)
```

I am trying to remove some code duplication, in particular the creation of the `fileInputStream` and `gcsOutputStream`. But I cannot simply extract those variables at the top of the method, because it would create resources outside of the scala-arm `managed` block:

```
import java.io.{ InputStream, OutputStream }
import java.nio.channels.Channels
import java.nio.file.{ Files, Path }
import java.util.zip.{ GZIPOutputStream, ZipInputStream }

import com.google.cloud.storage.{ BlobInfo, Storage }
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import resource._


class GcsService(gcsStorage: Storage) {

  def storeFileInGcs(localPath: Path, destination: FileDestination): Unit = {
    val blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(destination.bucket, destination.path).build

    // FIXME: creates a resource outside of the ARM block
    val fileInputStream = Files.newInputStream(localPath)
    val gcsOutputStream = Channels.newOutputStream(gcsStorage.writer(blobInfo))

    if (destination.unzipGzip) {
      unzipGzip(fileInputStream, gcsOutputStream)
    } else if (destination.decompressBzip2) {
      decompressBzip2(fileInputStream, gcsOutputStream)
    } else {
      copy(fileInputStream, gcsOutputStream)
    }
  }

  private def unzipGzip(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream): Unit = {
    for (input ← managed(new ZipInputStream(inputStream));
         output ← managed(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream))) {
      ByteStreams.copy(input, output)
    }
  }

  private def decompressBzip2(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream): Unit = {
    for (input <- managed(new BZip2CompressorInputStream(inputStream));
         output <- managed(outputStream)) {
      ByteStreams.copy(input, output)
    }
  }

  private def copy(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream): Unit = {
    for (input <- managed(inputStream);
         output <- managed(outputStream)) {
      IOUtils.copy(input, output)
    }
  }
}

case class FileDestination(unzipGzip: Boolean, decompressBzip2: Boolean, bucket: String, path: String)
```

As you can see, the code is a lot clearer and more testable, but resources are not handled correctly since they are not "managed". As an example, if an exception is thrown when creating `gcsOutputStream`, `fileInputStream` won't be closed.

I could probably solve this using [Google Guava sources and sinks](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IOExplained), but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this in Scala, without introducing Guava. Ideally using the standard library, or a scala-arm feature, or maybe even in `Cats`?

- Should I define `fileInputStream` and `gcsOutputStream` as functions that take nothing and return the stream? It seems the code will be more verbose with `() => InputStream` and `() => OutputStream` everywhere?
- Should I use multiple scala-arm "managed" for comprehensions (one to define `fileInputStream` and `gcsOutputStream`, and another one inside each sub-function)? If I do that, isn't it a problem that the "inner" inputstream will be closed twice?
- Is there a clean and "scalaish" approach to doing this that I am not seeing?

Comment: Are you on Scala 2.13? Have you considered using [scala.util.Using](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html) for some (all?) of your resource management?

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know about that new feature! Sadly, we are still on Scala 2.12, and it would be a big effort to migrate to Scala 2.13 due to technical debt, so probably in a few months... I'll migrate our `scala-arm` code to `Using` when we do. Is there a clean way to solve what I am trying to do with `Using` that is not available with `scala-arm`? If so, that might be an interesting answer to this question, and I guess I could use Guava sources/sinks until we migrate.

Comment: I would recommend using an _effect system_ which provides full resource management. Like [**cats-effect** `Resource`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/Resource.html) or [**zio** `Managed`](https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/datatypes_managed).

Comment: Or you can have a look at a Scala DSL for GCS that offer streaming and resource mngt like [Benji](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/) (I'm contributor of)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez : indeed, using an `effect system` might be the best approach to solve this cleanly. I guess it would mean moving from our current "java style" to a more "functional programming style". I'm going to look into cats-effect / zio. I would be really interested to see an answer that shows how the code would look with that approach.

@cchantep : thanks a lot for suggesting Benji, I didn't know about it and it looks very interesting. Sadly, I can't add too many dependencies like Play / Akka, we are actually trying to reduce the number of dependencies in this project.

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor it like this:

First, declare managed resources:

```
val fileInputStream: ManagedResource[InputStream] = managed(Files.newInputStream(localPath))
val gcsOutputStream: ManagedResource[OutputStream] = managed(Channels.newOutputStream(gcsStorage.writer(blobInfo)))
```

It doesn't open these resources, it's just declaration, that you want these resources to be managed.

Then you could use `map` to wrap them in desired decorators (like `ZipInputStream`):

```
if (destination.unzipGzip) {
  for (input ← fileInputStream.map(s => new ZipInputStream(s));
       output ← gcsOutputStream.map(s => new GZIPOutputStream(s))) {
    ByteStreams.copy(input, output)
  }
} else if (destination.decompressBzip2) {
  for (input <- fileInputStream.map(s => new BZip2CompressorInputStream(s));
       output <- gcsOutputStream) {
    ByteStreams.copy(input, output)
  }
} else {
  for (input <- fileInputStream;
       output <- gcsOutputStream) {
    IOUtils.copy(input, output)
  }
}
```

Of course `ManagedResource[A]` is just value, so you can even pass it to a method as parameter:

```
private def unzipGzip(inputStream: Managed[InputStream], outputStream: Managed[OutputStream]): Unit = {
  for (input ← inputStream.map(s => new ZipInputStream(s));
       output ← outputStream.map(s => new GZIPOutputStream(s))) {
    ByteStreams.copy(input, output)
  }
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach, but the "wrapping" `ZipInputStream` / `GZIPOutputStream` / `BZip2CompressorInputStream` sadly won't be closed, only the inner `fileInputStream`/ `gcsOutputStream `.
That's because the scala-arm `map()` method does not "manage" the result of the map operation (which may be anything, not always a wrapping resource).
It wouldn't be a problem if the wrapping resources were stateless, but sadly that's not the case (e.g. we need to close the `ZipInputStream`'s inflater to close the associated native ZLIB resources).

Comment: So the behavior would be similar to having a single for-comprehension at the top that "manages" the `fileInputStream` / `gcsOutputStream`, and then wrapping those streams in sub-methods without using additional `managed` for-comprehensions.

Comment: @EtienneNeveu Maybe it could be done with flatMap, I will check it and update my answer.